# How can I set different Jenkins credentials depending on the git branch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins Multibranch project, and I need to set some credentials depending on the Git branch I'm on right now. For example:

```
# If I'm in master
MY_VARIABLE = credentials("master-credential")

# If I'm in develop
MY_VARIABLE = credentials("develop-credential")

# If I'm in QA
MY_VARIABLE = credentials("qa-credential")
```

Right now, I've tried to name my variables with a different prefix and setting them up in the following way:

```js
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        MY_VARIABLE = credentials("${env.BRANCH_NAME}-credential")
    }
    stages {
        stage("Start") {
            steps {
                # use MY_VARIABLE on my steps
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

I think I might be able to use different domains for my credentials and then specify the domain when I set them, but I haven't found in the docs how to specify the domains on the Jenkinsfile.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using the convenience function for `credentials` in the `environment` directive is cleaner, for interpolated strings resolved like this in the `credentialsId` you would need to use the `withCredentials` plugin and step method. Based on the question, I will assume the type bindings you want are for `string`:

```
steps {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}-credential", variable: 'MY_VARIABLE')]) {
    # use MY_VARIABLE on my steps
  }
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) for more information.